# Verify backup content without recreating it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help with a problem:

I have a *.bak file that i need to check for its contents on a certain table, however because of circumstances I cannot restore it on the server.

I tried to open it using Libreoffice calc, without success, because of few workplace circumstances using excel is not an option.

How can i open and search for the data in this *.bak file?

Comment: You cannot "open" a `.bak` file. You need to restore it to an instance.

Comment: Unfortunally, as I mentioned in my question, restoring it on the server will not be a possibility.

Comment: Then you won't be able to interact with the file, @Fernando.

Comment: @Fernando Can you elaborate on these "circumstances" please? Are you out of disk space, do you have insufficient rights, does the SQL version not match, do you receive a specific error, ... ? Otherwise the previous comment of Larnu is your final answer.

Comment: Idera's SQL Safe Backup allows you to attach virtual databases from a .bak file **without** having to do a restore. I've used it and it's been a life saver. They offer a free trial as well. https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver/sqlsafebackup

Comment: Lamu disc space is one of the problems, is not that there is not enough space, but is very limitated, and restore it will overwrite the costumer data, and that would not be a good choise. Also i have limitated rights on the server.
I will try the Critical Error suggestion.

Comment: *"and restore it will overwrite the costumer data"* only if you restore it over it, it won't if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

You won't able to see anything on *.bak file. If you want to make a verification I suggest that you make a database script export (structure and data) and compare it with the previous version (without certain table) and if that table is refereed inside that script.

[image: generate scripts]